# where is the problem in my python script?

Tags: python

```
N = int(input("saisir un entier: "))

if 10<=N<100 :
    print(N)
    if N % 3 and 6  == 0:
        print(N ,"est un nombre valide totale")
    else:
        print(N ,"n'est pas un nombre valide totale")
    
else:
    print ("repeat")
```

Comment: If you mean to check if N is a multiple of 3 and of 6, then you just need to check if `N%6 == 0`. Any multiple of 6 is a multiple of 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that 6 is never equal to zero, in this line:

```
if N % 3 and 6 == 0:
```

In Python, the above is interpreted as:

```
if (N % 3) and (6 == 0):
```

Perhaps you meant this?

```
if N % 3 == 0 and N % 6 == 0:
```

Or even simpler, because any multiple of 6 is also a multiple of 3:

```
if N % 6 == 0:
```

Comment: I accepted your answer and thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

your if statement is not doing what you think it is doing. while python is like english it is not really english. you need to do something like this:

`if N % 3 == 0 and N % 6 == 0`

the python interpreter is not "smart" enough to know you mean to check both 3 and 6 for you unless you explicitly state it.